# data appears as null on redshift external table while working right on athena

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, amazon-athena, amazon-redshift-spectrum

So I'm trying to run the following simple query on redshift spectrum:

```
select * from company.vehicles where vehicle_id is not null
```

and it return 0 rows(all of the rows in the table are null). However when I run the same query on athena it works fine and return results. Tried msck repair but both athena and redshift are using the same metastore so it shouldn't matter.
I also don't see any errors.

The format of the files is orc.

The create table query is:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE 'vehicles'(
  'vehicle_id' bigint, 
  'parent_id' bigint, 
  'client_id' bigint, 
  'assets_group' int, 
  'drivers_group' int)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  'dt' string, 
  'datacenter' string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://company-rt-data/metadata/out/vehicles/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'CrawlerSchemaDeserializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'CrawlerSchemaSerializerVersion'='1.0',  
  'classification'='orc', 
  'compressionType'='none')
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually it turned out to be a bug in redshift. In order to fix it, we needed to run the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name SET TABLE properties(‘orc.schema.resolution’=‘position’);
```

Comment: Do you have any further details on this bug? I have a similar issue, although it is only some columns not appearing. They appear ok in athena though.

Comment: Hello @confytoday, did you found a solution? For me also only some columns are empty and nothing from here can't solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

How did you create your external table ??
For Spectrum,you have to explicitly set the parameters to treat what should be treated as null

add the parameter **'serialization.null.format'=''** in TABLE PROPERTIES so that all columns with '' will be treated as NULL to your external table in spectrum

**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE external_schema.your_table_name(
)
row format delimited
    fields terminated by ','
    stored as textfile 
LOCATION [filelocation]
TABLE PROPERTIES('numRows'='100', 'skip.header.line.count'='1','serialization.null.format'='');
```

**

Alternatively,you can setup the SERDE-PROPERTIES while creating the external table which will automatically recognize NULL values

Comment: The property you mention is relevant to data of type text only. You should use it in case you have text file with empty fields that you want spectrum to read as null. However my data type is orc - I have added the create table query. My problem is that redshift displays all the rows as null though they do contain data. On athena I can see the data properly.@theDbGuy

Comment: Alright.May i ask where is the file stored ? Is it in athena or spectrum catalog

Comment: The data is stored in s3 and the metadata is stored in glue data catalog @theDbGuy

Comment: can you choose one record from athena(that is returned when u execute the NOT NULL condition) using a primay key or something and try to select the same in spectrum and let me know if the outputs match

Comment: If possible,try using the glue crawler to create the table instead of using the CREATE statement

Comment: tried both still redshift does not return anything. I also tried to change the table's location because spectrum works fine with other orc based  external tables. I also tried to create a different not related table with the same orc file and redshift returned null, but when I query the data with spark it works fine. This is so weird. @theDbGuy

Comment: do you mean that you created a separate external table in spectrum schema instead of your glue metastore?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found this solution.

In my case I had external tables that were created with Athena pointing to an S3 bucket that contained heavily nested JSON data. To access them with Redshift I used `json_serialization_enable to true;` before my queries to make the nested JSON columns queryable. This lead to some columns being `NULL` when the JSON exceeded a size limit, see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/serializing-complex-JSON.html):

> If the serialization overflows the maximum VARCHAR size of 65535, the cell is set to NULL.

To solve this issue I used Amazon Redshift Spectrum instead of serialization: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-query-nested-data.html.